# What's the meaning of "vectors cv lie along a line"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading the Linear algebra book by Gilbert Strang. In the first chapter, there's a line (see last two lines in the picture) saying that "vectors $c\mathbf{v}$ lie along a line". I am not able to understand the meaning of this line. Have we constrained ([This is the paragraph containing that line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ6ql.jpg)) ourselves to make v a vector of 2 dimensions here? Because, in that case, we can plot all the points and that would create a line. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This is sloppily formulated. What is intended is that the set $\{\,c\mathbf v\mid c\in\Bbb R\,\}$ forms a line (through the origin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example $v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and we can multiply it by some constant $c$ to get $cv = \begin{bmatrix} c \\ c \end{bmatrix}$. As you've said, if you plot all of these points then you'll end up with a line, the line $y = x$.

We haven't constrained ourselves to 2 dimensions here, as an example if $v$ was instead $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ then we've added an extra dimension by it's still the same line.

Comment: Then we'll be able to plot all the points on that line. So what do they mean by "if w is not on that line". Can you give me an example of w which is not on that line?

Comment: The map $l\colon c\mapsto cv$ is a parametrisation of a line.  A vector is member of this line iff it is in the image of $l$ that is iff there's a number $c$ such that $w=cv$, i.e., $v\parallel w$.

Comment: @SiddhantBashisth An example would be $w = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. If you did the same process of plotting all the points that $cw$ gives then you would end up with a different line, $x = 0$, because $w$ goes in a different direction.

Comment: @David We can plot points for any number of dimensions. So even if v is an n-dimensional (having all none zero terms) vector, cv would still lie along a line. Right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much